# Tools provided by Google to measure the performance in the cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have to write a report about Cloud Computing and QoS, and I need information about the tools that Providers provide customers to measure the performances of services. Does anyone know if Google provides any such tool?
I apologize for any grammatical errors :)
Thank you for support

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by "performance", because there are many aspects, factors, etc. that can all be considered related to performance, including compute, storage, network, boot times, price/performance, etc.

Since your question is generic, you might want to read a couple of references below to get an overview of the types of performance measurements that can be performed and what tools, frameworks, etc. are generally used.

In no particular order, here are some references to tools and APIs from Google:

- [`gsutil` (storage) performance diagnostics](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/perfdiag)
- [Measuring network performance with Resource Timing API](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/12/measuring-network-performance-with.html)

benchmark suites from third parties:

- [AMPLab Big Data Benchmark](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/benchmark/)
- [Intel Cloud Object Storage Benchmark](https://github.com/intel-cloud/cosbench)

and benchmark results from third parties:

- [Google Compute Engine benchmarking by Scalr](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/scalr-and-google-compute-engine.html)
- [The Cloud Performance Dashboard: A Quick Market Overview](http://gigaom.com/2010/08/16/dialing-up-a-dashboard-for-cloud-performance/)
- [By the numbers: How Google Compute Engine stacks up to Amazon EC2](https://gigaom.com/2013/03/15/by-the-numbers-how-google-compute-engine-stacks-up-to-amazon-ec2/)
- [MongoDB on Google Compute Engine – tips and benchmarks](https://blog.serverdensity.com/mongodb-on-google-compute-engine-tips-and-benchmarks/)
- [Performance analysis of GAE and AWS](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~jain/cse567-11/ftp/clouds/)
- [Google Compute Engine Performance Test with RightScale and Apica](http://www.rightscale.com/blog/cloud-industry-insights/google-compute-engine-performance-test-rightscale-and-apica)
- [Measuring and Comparing the Performance of 5 Cloud Platforms](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/07/Benchmarking-5-Cloud-Platforms)
- [Cassandra performance benchmark by Stackdriver](http://www.stackdriver.com/cassandra-aws-gce-rackspace/)
- [DataStax Enterprise Testing on Google Compute Engine](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-enterprise-testing-on-google-compute-engine)
- [Google Compute Engine vs Amazon EC2 Part 2: Synthetic CPU and Memory Benchmarks](http://datacommunitydc.org/blog/2013/01/google-compute-engine-vs-amazon-ec2-part-2-synthetic-cpu-and-memory-benchmarks/)